# Laravel 5.4 : Writing SQL query in Model

Tags: sql, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am working on a small laravel project where I use to write all my sql queries in the controller and then sent the data to the view.

This is a function from my controller:

```
 public function view_all_applicants($job_id,$job_title)
    {

        $sql = DB::select("SELECT jm.`jobseeker_id`,jm.`jobseeker_name`,jm.`jobseeker_phone`,jm.`login_email`,jm.`jobseeker_coverletter`,jm.`jobseeker_cv`,
                  jm.`jobseeker_education`,jm.`jobseeker_experience`,jm.`jobseeker_linkedin`,aj.`cover_letter`,aj.`date_applied`
                  FROM `jobseeker_main` AS jm
                  JOIN `applicants_for_job` AS aj ON jm.`jobseeker_id`=aj.`jobseeker_id`
                  JOIN `job_details` AS jd ON jm.`jobseeker_id`=jd.`job_id`
                  WHERE aj.`job_id`=$job_id");

        $count = DB::select("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(aj.`afj_id`)) AS total FROM `jobseeker_main` AS jm
                             JOIN `applicants_for_job` AS aj ON jm.`jobseeker_id`=aj.`jobseeker_id`
                             JOIN `job_details` AS jd ON jm.`jobseeker_id`=jd.`job_id` WHERE aj.`job_id`=$job_id");

        foreach($count as $ss)
        {
            $data['total'] = $ss->total;
        }

        return view('company.applicants_for_job',$data,compact('sql'));     

    }
```

As you can see I am running two sql queries here and then I sent the data to the views. My question is, is there anyway where I can write my queries in Model (instead of controller) and then sent the result to the views? I am new to Laravel. Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can quite literally put the above code in a method in your relevant Model, and call that method.  However, one would generally not call a Model method from their View directly.  The Controller should assemble the data needed for the View, and therefore, the Controller should pull the data from the Model, and then pass it to the View.

for example:

MyModel.php

```
class MyModel {


    public function getX($job_id) {
       $sql = DB::select("SELECT jm.`jobseeker_id`,jm.`jobseeker_name`,jm.`jobseeker_phone`,jm.`login_email`,jm.`jobseeker_coverletter`,jm.`jobseeker_cv`,
                  jm.`jobseeker_education`,jm.`jobseeker_experience`,jm.`jobseeker_linkedin`,aj.`cover_letter`,aj.`date_applied`
                  FROM `jobseeker_main` AS jm
                  JOIN `applicants_for_job` AS aj ON jm.`jobseeker_id`=aj.`jobseeker_id`
                  JOIN `job_details` AS jd ON jm.`jobseeker_id`=jd.`job_id`
                  WHERE aj.`job_id`=$job_id");

        return $sql;
    }

    public function getCount() {
       $count = DB::select("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(aj.`afj_id`)) AS total FROM `jobseeker_main` AS jm
                             JOIN `applicants_for_job` AS aj ON jm.`jobseeker_id`=aj.`jobseeker_id`
                             JOIN `job_details` AS jd ON jm.`jobseeker_id`=jd.`job_id` WHERE aj.`job_id`=$job_id");

        return $count;
    }
}
```

Controller.php

```
public function __construct(MyModel $model)
{
   $this->model = $model;
}

public function index(Request $request, $job_id) {

   $x = $this->model->getX($job_id);
   $count = $this->model->count();

   $data['x'] = $x;
   $data['count'] = $count;

   return view('company.applicants_for_job',$data);

}
```

UPDATE:

See edits above per comment.

Comment: How can I pass the variables to the Model? For example, the variable $job_id in first query.